# how to split the elements in list and combine with another list in python

Tags: python, list

`list1 = ['APPLE - BANANA - (40-0)', 'BANANA :', 'ORANGE', 'MELON', 'MILK :', 'SET - "A" FISH', '$ 750', 'RANK :'`

First, I would like to split the [0] and [5]
Output like:

`'APPLE','BANANA','(40-0)'` and `'SET','A','FISH'`

how can I split it? For more information, actually I only need

`'APPLE','BANANA','ORANGE','SET','A'` for my next use, is it possible to take them out?

and here is

`list2[0] = ['3', '10', 'JASON', 'T361', 'ZAC', 'ANDY', '120', '1085', '3', '2-1/2', '4', '7', '3', '0:57.80', '4.7']`  here is the [0] position means there are some more like this format below.

so follow up the first part, i would like to insert

`'APPLE','BANANA','ORANGE','SET','A'` into `list2`'s every elements and maybe take `JASON` be the first element. Could anyone tell me how to do it? thank you.

Answer (score 0):

```
list1 = ['APPLE - BANANA - (40-0)', 'BANANA :', 'ORANGE', 'MELON', 'MILK :', 'SET - "A" FISH', '$ 750', 'RANK :']
list2 = []
list2.append(list1[0])
name_of_array = []
str = ""
for i in list2:
  for t in i:
        if t == '-' or t == '(' or t == ')' or t == ':' or t == "4" or t == "0":
           pass
        elif t == ' ':
           name_of_array.append(str)
           str = ""
        else:
           str += t
list3 = []
name_of_array1 = []
list3.append(list1[5])
str2 = ""
for r in list3:
    for e in r:
        if e == '-' or e == '(' or e == ')' or e == ':' or e == '"':
           pass
        elif e == ' ':
           name_of_array1.append(str2)
           str2 = ""
        else:
           str2 += e
name_of_array1.append(str2)
compose_2_lists = name_of_array + name_of_array1
big_list = []
for i in compose_2_lists:
    if i =='':
        pass
    else:
        big_list.append(i)
```

That's how I would do it. I hope I helped. If you not happy please talk with me, I'll try to explain in other way.

Comment: thank you for your reply. but my `list2` already contains something, so maybe i change your list2 to list4, something like that?

Comment: Yes, you can :)

Comment: sorry I have tried but it seems cant have the correct output.
if i output big_list from above code, it will show ```'APPLE','BANANA','ORANGE','SET','A'```
but it doesnt combine to every list2 elements. could you please check?